# How to show current location icon in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am creating an app in Xcode. I have a different pins on the mapView, but I ant to change one of the pins, to be the current location (the "radar"-looking) icon with a different color showing. How can I do this?

Here is the code I have currently:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {    
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        pin.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8823529412, green: 0.1647058824, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
        return pin
    } else {
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")  
        annotationView.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007843137255, green: 0.3803921569, blue: 0.8156862745, alpha: 1)          
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? Do you receive an error? Please explain the actual behaviour you see, not just the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    let pin = mapView.view(for: annotation) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    pin.pinTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8823529412, green: 0.1647058824, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1)
    return pin
    // ...
```

just return `nil` and `MapKit` will automatically show the user location icon:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
} else {
    // ...
```